# subset data based on y/m/d/h and get error ouputs

Tags: r, date, subset

tail(subset(PJM,Dates<="2015-06-01 01:00:00"))

wouldnt figure out why it would happen..try to subset data based off Dates.

```
               Dates   Number Hour    Price Load Holiday   NG
3625 2015-06-01 00:00:00 42156.00   00 19.06607 1395       0 2.66
3626 2015-06-01 01:00:00 42156.04   01 17.06193 1371       0 2.66
3627 2015-06-01 02:00:00 42156.08   02 15.51676 1380       0 2.66
3628 2015-06-01 03:00:00 42156.12   03 18.42535 1402       0 2.66
3629 2015-06-01 04:00:00 42156.17   04 23.55589 1503       0 2.66
3630 2015-06-01 05:00:00 42156.21   05 26.15626 1661       0 2.66
```

Comment: i think they are different..

Comment: They're not.  You're comparing a `Date` vector to a `character` vector, which doesn't work.  You need to use `as.Date(...)`.